# Use of escaped strings as html element ids in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating html element ids by escaping text phrases, as follows:

```
var elementid=escape('some term entered by user');
```

As a result, I have a span with an id as follows:

```
<span class="radio" id="selectTimescalesOne%20hello%20there" style="background-position: 0px 0px; "></span>
```

If I attempt this:

```
$('#selectTimescalesOne%20hello%20there').html('some new stuff');
```

Then the span does not get updated.  Is there something wrong with using escaped strings as `id`s?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uSwEJ/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you will need to replace the spaces by something else, e.g. underscore `_`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%` is not valid in an id. You are limited to alphanumeric characters, `_`, `-` ':' and `.`, although it is wise not to use the latter three, because they cannot be used in CSS selectors.

I really wouldn't know why you want a user to input your id. Seems like bad design. If you do want to do this, just remove any invalid character or replace it with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing whitespace (using a regex) with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the spaces in the text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), you can't use a '%' in your ID.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think it would be best to strip any special characters and replace all white spaces with dashes or underscores.